# Can't compile surf, gcr-3.pc not found, glib.h not found

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, pkg-config

I'm trying to compile surf browser from source with little success.
It looks like I miss gcr-3.pc.

edit : I'm on Ubuntu 19.04

```
c99 `pkg-config --cflags x11` `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 gcr-3 webkit2gtk-4.0` -DVERSION=\"2.0\" -DWEBEXTDIR=\"/usr/lib/surf\"  -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -DGCR_API_SUBJECT_TO_CHANGE -fPIC -O -c common.c
Package gcr-3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gcr-3.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH prints nothing. I have installed pkg-config (`pkg-config is already the newest version (0.29.1-0ubuntu2)`), so where should I fetch it? Reading about pkg-config on other distro forums shows it should be in /usr/lib/pkgconfig, but I have only one file, ibus-table.pc

Also, `surf.c:8:10: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory`
But I do have glib!

```bsh
>> cd /usr/include/glib-2.0
>> ls -a
.   gio   glib.h         glib-unix.h  gobject
..  glib  glib-object.h  gmodule.h
```

I'm really annoyed and could not find any document listing dependancies for compiling surf, even surf's readme just says "you need GTK+ and Webkit/GTK+ header files". I think I got them, why isn't anything working? I haven't even modified anything yet!

Full make output (with a lot of warnings about types) :

```
>> sudo make clean install
rm -f surf surf.o common.o
rm -f libsurf-webext.so libsurf-webext.o
surf build options:
CC            = c99
Package gcr-3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gcr-3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gcr-3' found
CFLAGS        =   -DVERSION="2.0" -DWEBEXTDIR="/usr/lib/surf"  -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -DGCR_API_SUBJECT_TO_CHANGE -fPIC -O
WEBEXTCFLAGS  = -fPIC -pthread -I/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -O
LDFLAGS       = 
c99 -fPIC `pkg-config --cflags webkit2gtk-4.0 webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0` -O -c libsurf-webext.c
libsurf-webext.c: In function ‘msgsurf’:
libsurf-webext.c:48:42: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wformat=]
  if ((ret = snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "%c%c%s",
                                         ~^
                                         %ld
                      2 + sln, p ? p->id : 0, s))
                      ~~~~~~~              
libsurf-webext.c:48:44: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘guint64’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wformat=]
  if ((ret = snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "%c%c%s",
                                           ~^
                                           %ld
                      2 + sln, p ? p->id : 0, s))
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
libsurf-webext.c: In function ‘readpipe’:
libsurf-webext.c:84:2: warning: ‘webkit_dom_document_get_default_view’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (!p || !(view = webkit_dom_document_get_default_view(
  ^~
In file included from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkitdom/webkitdom.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/WebKitFrame.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/webkit-web-extension.h:33,
                 from libsurf-webext.c:7:
/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkitdom/WebKitDOMDocument.h:640:1: note: declared here
 webkit_dom_document_get_default_view(WebKitDOMDocument* self);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libsurf-webext.c:92:3: warning: ‘webkit_dom_dom_window_get_inner_width’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   ww = webkit_dom_dom_window_get_inner_width(view);
   ^~
In file included from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkitdom/webkitdom.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/WebKitFrame.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/webkit-web-extension.h:33,
                 from libsurf-webext.c:7:
/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkitdom/WebKitDOMDOMWindow.h:371:1: note: declared here
 webkit_dom_dom_window_get_inner_width(WebKitDOMDOMWindow* self);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libsurf-webext.c:93:3: warning: ‘webkit_dom_dom_window_scroll_by’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   webkit_dom_dom_window_scroll_by(view,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkitdom/webkitdom.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/WebKitFrame.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/webkit-web-extension.h:33,
                 from libsurf-webext.c:7:
/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkitdom/WebKitDOMDOMWindow.h:191:1: note: declared here
 webkit_dom_dom_window_scroll_by(WebKitDOMDOMWindow* self, gdouble x, gdouble y);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libsurf-webext.c:99:3: warning: ‘webkit_dom_dom_window_get_inner_height’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   wh = webkit_dom_dom_window_get_inner_height(view);
   ^~
In file included from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkitdom/webkitdom.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/WebKitFrame.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/webkit-web-extension.h:33,
                 from libsurf-webext.c:7:
/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkitdom/WebKitDOMDOMWindow.h:358:1: note: declared here
 webkit_dom_dom_window_get_inner_height(WebKitDOMDOMWindow* self);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libsurf-webext.c:100:3: warning: ‘webkit_dom_dom_window_scroll_by’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   webkit_dom_dom_window_scroll_by(view,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkitdom/webkitdom.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/WebKitFrame.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkit2/webkit-web-extension.h:33,
                 from libsurf-webext.c:7:
/usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/webkitdom/WebKitDOMDOMWindow.h:191:1: note: declared here
 webkit_dom_dom_window_scroll_by(WebKitDOMDOMWindow* self, gdouble x, gdouble y);
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c99 `pkg-config --cflags x11` `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 gcr-3 webkit2gtk-4.0` -DVERSION=\"2.0\" -DWEBEXTDIR=\"/usr/lib/surf\"  -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -DGCR_API_SUBJECT_TO_CHANGE -fPIC -O -c common.c
Package gcr-3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gcr-3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gcr-3' found
c99 -shared -Wl,-soname,libsurf-webext.so  -o libsurf-webext.so \
    libsurf-webext.o common.o `pkg-config --libs webkit2gtk-4.0 webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0`
c99 `pkg-config --cflags x11` `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 gcr-3 webkit2gtk-4.0` -DVERSION=\"2.0\" -DWEBEXTDIR=\"/usr/lib/surf\"  -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -DGCR_API_SUBJECT_TO_CHANGE -fPIC -O -c surf.c
Package gcr-3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gcr-3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gcr-3' found
surf.c:8:10: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glib.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:24: surf.o] Error 1
```

I installed all these dependencies manually before make-ing:

```
build-essential
pkg-config
libglib2.0-dev
libgcc-4.8-dev
libseed-gtk4-dev
libgtk-3-dev
webkit2gtk-4.0
gdb
gdb-debug
dmenu
```

Thanks for reading this whole post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terminal, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libgcr-3-dev` <-- That is [for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gcr-3.pc). You did not say what Ubuntu version you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I'm on Ubuntu 19.04. Edited and added.
Also, with `libgcr-3-dev` installed it seems to be working, so thanks for your answer!